# How to fix react-native-events-calendar error

Tags: react-native

I'm using https://github.com/joshjhargreaves/react-native-event-calendar 
to make a simple dayview calendar in react native.

I have an external tablet for testing purposes by using Expo. When running my application, the stacktrace on the tablet shows an error:

[image]

, but I can't seem to find where this error is in the files. VS code / metro bundler doesnt show this error though, it shows some warnings;

```
Warning: Failed frame type: The frame `frame.length` is marked as required in `VirtualizedList.getItemLayout`, but its value is `undefined`.

Warning: Failed child context type: Invalid child context `virtualizedCell.cellKey` of type `number` supplied to `CellRenderer`, expected `string`.
```

Code where I use the import:

```
    <View style={styles.calendarHolder}>
    <EventCalendar>
  events={this.state.events}
  width={width}
  initDate={'2017-09-08'}
    </EventCalendar>

</View>
```

This problem only occurs when I import react-native-events-calendar / use it. When I don't do this, my app works fine, so it should have something to do with the calendar. However, I can't find a lot of documentation and since I can't find the place of the error either, I'm kind of stuck. How can I fix this? I'm also open for other recommendations for a simple dayview calendar / agenda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the EventCalendar component wrong.Use it like below

```
<EventCalendar
  events={this.state.events}
  width={width}
  initDate={'2017-09-08'}
/>
```

Instead of

```
<EventCalendar>
 events={this.state.events}
 width={width}
 initDate={'2017-09-08'}
</EventCalendar>
```